# Sent her an email with or about?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, prepositional-phrases, proper-nouns

Which one is correct to say?

> I have sent her an email with instruction about how to add mailboxes into her outlook
>
> I have sent her an email about how to add mailboxes into her outlook.

Comment: I wouldn't write "... **into** her outlook.", rather "... **in** her Outlook". Outlook capitalized because it is the trade name of a specific program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second sentence implies that the e-mail contains no other significant content.   Those instructions are the entire point of the e-mail.

The first sentence doesn't have this implication.   Those instructions are included, but other things might be included as well.

If the e-mail does include other things, the first sentence is a better choice.

The phrasing "instructions about" doesn't sound quite natural to me.   It isn't wrong, but I would recommend "instructions for adding" as a better option than "instructions about how to add".